# Unable to connect mysql database in NestJS with Typeorm - ERROR: this.mysql.createPool is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Currently, I'm starting to learn about the Nestjs and perform some crud operation but before start, I'm stuck in a database connection issue.

Also, My scenario is different compared to a normal database connection. I'm fetching the database credential from the Azure key vault then after I will put the credential in app.module.ts.

But, Every time it shows `this.mysql.createPool is not a function` error message. I don't know why.

Also, you can refer below screenshot.

[image]

Also, I have put some code below for your understanding.

**azureKeyVault.service.ts**

```
import { KeyVaultSecret, SecretClient } from '@azure/keyvault-secrets';
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

interface credential {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface dbConfig {
  type: string;
  host: string;
  port: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  database: string;
  entities: [string];
  synchronize: boolean;
  autoLoadEntities: boolean;
  retryAttempts: number;
}

@Injectable()
class AzureKeyVaultService {
  /**
   * Azure key vault service
   */
  public async azureKeyVault() {
    const keyVaultEndpoint = 
`https://${process.env.AZURE_KV_ENDPOINT}.vault.azure.net`;

    /* Fetch Default Azure Credential */
    const credential: DefaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    // /* Create server client using endpoint and credential */
    const client: SecretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultEndpoint, credential);
    return await client.getSecret(process.env.AZURE_KV_NAME);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  public async databaseConfiguration(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    const { value }: KeyVaultSecret = await this.azureKeyVault();
    const dbCredentialData = JSON.parse(value);
    console.log('dbCredentialData', dbCredentialData);
    const { username, password }: credential =
      dbCredentialData[process.env.AZURE_KV_KEY];

    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      driver: 'MysqlDriver',
      host: dbCredentialData?.masterhost,
      port: 3306,
      username: 'development',
      password: password,
      database: process.env.DB_MAIN,
      entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.js'],
      synchronize: false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      retryAttempts: 1,
    };
  }
}

const AzureKeyVault = new AzureKeyVaultService();
export { AzureKeyVault };
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AzureKeyVault } from './config/azureKeyVault.service';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    // TypeOrmModule.forRoot(AzureKeyVault.databaseConfiguration()),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => AzureKeyVault.databaseConfiguration(),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

If anyone knows what is the issue please reply.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After many searches around the issue. I have found there is no major issue. only I need to remove one extra parameter `driver` in the azureKeyVault.service.ts file.

Final return object is as follows.

```
return {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: dbCredentialData?.masterhost,
  port: 3306,
  username: 'development',
  password: password,
  database: process.env.DB_MAIN,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.js'],
  synchronize: false,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  retryAttempts: 1,
};
```